# Dynamically prevent certain fields from being serialized with Jackson's PropertyFilter

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to be able to prevent certain fields of objects from being serialized, primarily based on their type. For example, consider the following Object:

```
class MyPojo {
    private int myInt;
    private boolean myBoolean;

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I would like to be able to, when serializing, not serialize the boolean field if it is false. Or not serialize the int if it's zero. Basically, not serialize any particular field based on any property of either it's type or particular value.

I'm aware of JsonSerializers, which I used to partially solve my problem, but it is [impossible to choose not to serialize a field in a JsonSerializer](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-core/issues/177#issuecomment-166383734).

The closest I've come is implementing my own PropertyFilter, and applying it to my Object via `@JsonFilter`:

```
public class XmlPropertyFilter implements PropertyFilter {
    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        JavaType type = writer.getType();

        if (writer instanceof BeanPropertyWriter) {
            BeanPropertyWriter bWriter = (BeanPropertyWriter) writer;

            String fieldName = bWriter.getSerializedName().getValue();
            Field f = pojo.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = f.get(pojo);

            if (!type.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(int.class) && value != null) {
                // Serialize everything that isn't an int and doesn't have a null value
                prov.defaultSerializeField(fieldName, value, gen);
            } else if (type.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(int.class)) {
                // Only serialize ints if the value isn't 0
                if (value != 0) prov.defaultSerializeField(fieldName, value, gen);
            }
        }

    }

    // ...
}
```

This does exactly what I want, except it has the nasty side effect of breaking wrapping (e.g. serializing a list). According to the `@JsonFilter` documentation, it is valid to apply a filter to a field rather than the entire class, which would be wonderful, but I've tried that and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, and it's exactly what I was looking for. The secret is the method `BeanPropertyWriter#serializeAsOmittedField(Object, JsonGenerator, SerializerProvider)`. This does exactly what is impossible to do inside of a JsonSerializer - it completely removed the field from the output.

Here's an example of this DynamicPropertyFilter:

```
public class DynamicPropertyFilter implements PropertyFilter {
    public void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        if (writer instanceof BeanPropertyWriter) {
            BeanPropertyWriter bWriter = (BeanPropertyWriter) writer;

            String fieldName = bWriter.getFullName().getSimpleName();
            Field field = pojo.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object object = field.get(pojo);

            if (Double.class.isInstance(object) && (double) object == 0.0) {
                // Remove all double fields that are equal to 0.0
                bWriter.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, prov);
                return;
            } else if (Boolean.class.isInstance(object)) {
                // Change all boolean fields to 1 and 0 instead of true and false
                prov.defaultSerializeField(fieldName, (boolean) object ? 1 : 0, jgen);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Serialize field as normal if property is not filtered
        writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
    }

    public void serializeAsElement(Object elementValue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        writer.serializeAsField(elementValue, jgen, prov);
    }

    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, JsonObjectFormatVisitor objectVisitor, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(objectVisitor, provider);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, ObjectNode propertiesNode, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(propertiesNode, provider);
    }
}
```

Not only can I filter fields, which is primarily what I wanted, but I can also change them (as seen in the boolean example). This eliminates the need for both a PropertyFilter and a JsonSerializer.